# Compiling CLD2 in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2013, linker, clr

I am trying to compile the chromium [compact language detector](https://code.google.com/p/cld2/) in Visual Studio 2013. I am actually trying to create a .NET Wrapper for the library so I have added all the source files inside my CLR project.

Now whenever I compile I get these linking errors.

```
error LNK2005: "struct CLD2::CLD2TableSummary const CLD2::kCjkDeltaBi_obj" (?kCjkDeltaBi_obj@CLD2@@3UCLD2TableSummary@1@B) already defined in cld_generated_cjk_delta_bi_32.obj
```

These all seems to be related as I can see a relation between the 'generated' files.

Problem is I have a lot of these and I am not sure which ones I should exclude and which I should keep and use in my code.

Here is a list all the generated files that came with the CLD2 code.

```
cld_generated_cjk_uni_prop_80.cc
cld_generated_score_quad_octa_2.cc
cld_generated_score_quad_octa_0122.cc
cld_generated_score_quad_octa_0122_2.cc
cld_generated_score_quad_octa_1024_256.cc
cld_generated_cjk_delta_bi_4.cc
cld_generated_cjk_delta_bi_32.cc
cld2_generated_octa2_dummy.cc
cld2_generated_quad0122.cc
cld2_generated_quad0720.cc
cld2_generated_quadchrome_2.cc
cld2_generated_quadchrome_16.cc
cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.cc
cld2_generated_deltaocta0122.cc
cld2_generated_deltaocta0527.cc
cld2_generated_deltaoctachrome.cc
cld2_generated_distinctocta0122.cc
cld2_generated_distinctocta0527.cc
cld2_generated_distinctoctachrome.cc
```

The naming convention of these suggests that I should only be using one of each group. At least that how I think I should use it as I am not really an expert in encoding nor in how CLD2 works. And I could not find any references online explaining how to configure it.

I tried eliminating the linking errors by keeping only one of each generated group:

for example: from `cld_generated_cjk_delta_bi_4` and `cld_generated_cjk_delta_bi_32` I kept the 32 version. And so on for the rest of the files.

Now this made CLD compile yet when I tried testing it with languages I noticed that the scores were way way off and it was behaving inexplicably bad.

I am not trying to support all languages I only need to support latin languages along with hebrew, arabic, japanese and chinese.

Can someone please explain how to configure CLD2 to compile and work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a CLR version of the [Compact Language Detector 2](https://github.com/CLD2Owners/cld2).

You can either use it directly from the [CLD2.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CLD2.Net/) nuget package or check the [source](https://github.com/diadistis/cld2.net).

Answer (score 1):

Open the compile_libs.sh file in a text editor.  At the bottom, there are 2 g++ commands to compile the library, one for the regular CLD2 and another for the full version.  The files used will be listed with each.  Copy the header and source files for whichever library you are compiling (regular or full) into your project and build.  You may have to add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to eliminate errors.

Comment: Thanks, I did not actually move passed it. However I ended up using NTextCat for language detection.